# Unable to proxy call to backend api for angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-httpclient, angular-cli-v6

I am following the guide to configure proxy to backend using angular CLI
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Angular Version I am using : 6

Details of my proxy-conf.json

```
{
  "/backend": {
    "target": "https://application-inCloud.predix.io",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "info",
    "timeout":10000 ,
    "changeOrigin": "true",
    "headers": {"Authorization":"Bearer token",
    "header2": "123"}
  }
}
```

Details of how I am calling api in my service
using HTTPCLIENT

```
    const url = "/backend/getSomething"
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({"Authorization":"Bearer token",
            "header2": "123"});
   return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers});
```

Error I am getting

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request https://application-inCloud.predix.io from localhost:4200 to https://application-inCloud.predix.io (ENOTFOUND) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

What I am doing wrong?

The API works fine when I try hitting it in postman.
**I have no control over the API, without proxy angular was making a preflight request and eventually failing with 403, so for dev I thought of using the proxy option**

Comment: It looks like `https://application-inCloud.predix.io` doesn't exist

Comment: well I cannot post the actual API, but it is just to describe that its a rest API in cloud.

Comment: Maybe try to use it with `ip` instead of servername.